# position absolute Image Aligned Center

Tags: html, css

I am using image gallery in which outer width is 100%. But image is going align left because gallery image position is absolute. I m trying to make aligned center plz help me.

outer div css code:

```
.wt-rotator .screen {
    height: 500px !important;
    left: -5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -11px;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

style on image css:

```
.wt-rotator .main-img {
    border: 0 none;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you remove the position:absolute style then?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding css properties `{left: 50%; right: 50%;}`